# $G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ as a subspace $G_n(\mathbb{C}^{\infty})$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to understand how $G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ is a subspace of $G_n(\mathbb{C}^{\infty}).$ My issue is that the first is the set of $n$-planes over a real vector space, while the second is over a complex vector space, making it equivalent instead to oriented $2n$-planes, so how can the former be a subspace of the latter?

Comment: So for each $n$-plane (thought of as a vector space), we tensor it with $\mathbb{C}$ and this gives a complex $n$-plane?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain more explicitly how the tensor product works (I'm not very well-versed in this). Are we tensoring over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: After a google search, I understand it now. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. I'm turning those comments into a short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the embedding is given by tensoring with $\Bbb C$.

We can identify $\Bbb C^\infty = \Bbb R^\infty \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C$. Under this identification, the map $\text{Gr}_n(\Bbb R^\infty) \to \text{Gr}_n(\Bbb C^\infty)$ is given by $V \mapsto V \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C \subset \Bbb R^\infty \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C$.

This is clearly injective and it's not terribly hard to see that it's continuous, though a little more care must be taken (that I am not going to take) to see that it's an embedding.

Comment: It's an injective map from a compact Hausdorff space to another, so everything is almost automatic.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: $\text{Gr}_n(\Bbb R^\infty)$ is not compact. The sequence of $n$-planes spanned by $(x_{i+1}, \dots, x_n)$ is a sequence with no convergent subsequence, e.g., or one can demonstrate a problematic open cover in the same way. Alternatively, we know its homology, which is nonzero in arbitrarily high degree, so it has cells of arbitrarily high dimension.

Comment: I think the relevant fact here is that the map is the limit of the respective maps on $\text{Gr}_n(\Bbb R^{n+k})$, and on these it's an embedding for the reasons you've stated. I'm not sure if that automatically implies that the map on $\text{Gr}_n(\Bbb R^\infty)$ is an embedding.

Comment: Ah. I thought these were the finite grassmanians. Indeed that works then because the topology is the weak one: the big $Gr$ is the limit of the small ones.

Comment: Good point, thanks.

Comment: To see that the map is continuous (at each finite level and, then, going to the limit, on the whole thing) one can use the fact that $Gr$ is a quotient of a Stieffel manifold and that your map is actually induced by a map of Stieffel  manifolds, which is an inclusion.